# How to change data.frame values that depend on a numericInput

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I'm no shiny pro and i'm struggling to make the data in a data.frame change when a `numericInput` is used in a function that the result goes in a matrix/data.frame. 
This is a toy example of my problem:

```
ui.R
library(DT)
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
           column(2,numericInput(inputId = "precentil",label = "percentile", 
                                 value = 0.9, min = 0.01, max=1, step = 0.01)),
           column(6,dataTableOutput("matResult")))
))


server.R
library(DT)
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data =  rnorm(1000)
  percentile = reactive({input$percentil})
  quant = reactive({quantile(data,percentile())})
  result = as.data.frame(c("quantile", quant))
  output$matResult =  DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(result,
                            options = list(paging = FALSE),rownames=F))

})
```

the error I get is: `Warning: Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class "c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")" to a data.frame` which i understand but i have search a lot and haven't found a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your data.frame to update, then you need to make it reactive and leave it reactive. And input values are already reactive. Seems like you're not groking reactive programming. I suggest you check out the [Effective Reactive Programming videos](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/) from the Shiny Developer conference. Also, this should work.

```
data <- rnorm(1000)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
  column(2,numericInput(inputId = "percentile",label = "percentile", 
                             value = 0.9, min = 0.01, max=1, step = 0.01)),
  column(6,dataTableOutput("matResult")))
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  result <- reactive({
    data.frame("quantile" = quantile(data, as.numeric(input$percentile) ))
  })
  output$matResult =  DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(result(),
                            options = list(paging = FALSE), rownames=F))
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: thanks it works, and thanks for the link for the tutorial